# Crear Tabla MYSQL temporal desde Metodo C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
public void crearTablaTemporal()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = Conexion.ObtenerConexion();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT 
        EXISTS temp_regiones AS (SELECT * FROM regiones)", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        MessageBox.Show("solo para detener el programa");
        con.Close();
    }
```

Básicamente lo que quiero es crear la tabla temporal desde una aplicación de windows forms C# y llenar esa tabla con una consulta. Esté método no da error, pero no crea la tabla temporal ni la llena con la consulta.
El comando para crear la tabla y llenar la tabla, lo probé directamente en la consola mysql y funciona correctamente.
De antemano gracias al que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es crear una tabla temporal, no necesitas un `DataAdapter`.  Puedes usar `ExecuteNonQuery()` asi:

```
public void crearTablaTemporal()
{
    MySqlConnection con = Conexion.ObtenerConexion();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT 
    EXISTS temp_regiones AS (SELECT * FROM regiones)", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("solo para detener el programa");
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Que extraño, sigue sin crear la tabla. Lo que hago es revisar por consola si la tabla fue creada, justo antes de que se cierre la conexión.

Comment: Si funciona, mi error fue el comprobar la existencia de la tabla mediante la consola, ahí nunca iba a aparecer. En en la aplicación c# si aparece, gracias por la ayuda.